# Call frame js from GWT

Tags: javascript, gwt

I am trying to call frame js from GWT.

my java code is:

```
 public class Trips extends MyPopup{
    Frame f = new Frame("js/location.html")

    public popupPanel(){
          super() ;
         setAddress(0d,0d,"asknjsnkjsd") ;

     }
     //other methods.object of this class is created while loading

    public static native void setAddress(Double lat,Double longitude,String address) /*-{
           $wnd.alert(address);
          $wnd.setAddress(lat,longitude,address) ;
     }-*/;
```

}

my js code is :

```
 var map ;
 var marker ;

 function initMap() {
var locat = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat("34.149486"),parseFloat("-117.257317"));

map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center : {
            lat : 34.149486,
            lng : -117.257317
        },
        zoom : 13
    });

myMap  = map;


marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position : {
        lat : 34.149486,
        lng : -117.257317
    },
    map : map,
    draggable : true,
    anchorPoint : new google.maps.Point(0, -29)
});

myMarker = marker ;

var geocoder = geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var card = document.getElementById('pac-card');
var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
var strictBounds = document.getElementById('strict-bounds-selector');

map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_RIGHT].push(card);

var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);

// Bind the map's bounds (viewport) property to the autocomplete object,
// so that the autocomplete requests use the current map bounds for the
// bounds option in the request.
autocomplete.bindTo('bounds', map);

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var infowindowContent = document.getElementById('infowindow-content');
infowindow.setContent(infowindowContent);

google.maps.event
        .addListener(
                marker,
                "dragend",
                function(e) {
                    var lat, lng, address;

                    geocoder
                            .geocode(
                                    {
                                        'latLng' : marker.getPosition()
                                    },
                                    function(results, status) {
                                        document
                                                .getElementById('pac-input').value = results[0].formatted_address;
                                        var latitide = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                        var longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                                        var addressLocation = results[0].formatted_address;
                                    });
                });

autocomplete.addListener('place_changed', function() {
    infowindow.close();
    marker.setVisible(false);
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();
    if (!place.geometry) {
        // User entered the name of a Place that was not suggested and
        // pressed the Enter key, or the Place Details request failed.
        window
                .alert("No details available for input: '" + place.name
                        + "'");
        return;
    }

    // If the place has a geometry, then present it on a map.
    if (place.geometry.viewport) {
        map.fitBounds(place.geometry.viewport);
    } else {
        map.setCenter(place.geometry.location);
        map.setZoom(17); // Why 17? Because it looks good.
    }
    marker.setPosition(place.geometry.location);
    marker.setVisible(true);

    var address = '';
    var latitide = place.geometry.location.lat();
    var longitude = place.geometry.location.lng();
    var addressLocation = place.formatted_address;
    if (place.address_components) {
        address = [
                (place.address_components[0]
                        && place.address_components[0].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[1]
                        && place.address_components[1].short_name || ''),
                (place.address_components[2]
                        && place.address_components[2].short_name || '') ]
                .join(' ');
    }

    infowindowContent.children['place-icon'].src = place.icon;
    infowindowContent.children['place-name'].textContent = place.name;
    infowindowContent.children['place-address'].textContent = address;
    infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

// Sets a listener on a radio button to change the filter type on Places
// Autocomplete.
}

 function setOriginAddressWithLatitude(lat,long,address){
     window
     .alert("No details available for input: '" + lat + " " + long +"  " + address
        + "'");

      document.getElementById('pac-input').value = address;
//initMap() ;
    map.setCenter(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long));
    marker.setPosition(new google.maps.LatLng(lat,long));

  }
```

html file is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
   <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_Key&libraries=places&callback=initMap"
        async defer></script>
    <script src = "location.js"></script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">

  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="pac-card" id="pac-card">
      <div id="pac-container">
        <input id="pac-input" type="text"
            placeholder="Enter a location" value = "St Marys Rd Sydney NSW 2000 Australia">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="infowindow-content">
      <img src="" width="16" height="16" id="place-icon">
      <span id="place-name"  class="title"></span><br>
      <span id="place-address"></span>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am getting following error in this
 **Cannot set property 'value' of null**   on line   document.getElementById('pac-input').value = address;

if i remove above line.I am getting error  **map.setCenter is not a function**

Comment: did you try moving script tags at the bottom of the body? that way you will be sure the initialize script is triggered after the static dom is initialized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i used following

```
public native void setOriginAddressWithLatitude(Double latitude,Double longitude,String address) /*-{
        var iframe  = $doc.getElementById("viewMapIFrame");
        iframe.contentWindow.setOriginAddressWithLatitude(latitude,longitude,address) ;
    }-*/;
```